# Add new filter to solution explorer via VS package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to add a new filter as part of an extension I'm writing for VS. Microsoft has provided a walkthrough here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh966591.aspx

However, I can't get just the basic walkthrough working, my filter button shows up in the right place, but I can't get it to actually do anything when I click on it. I'm guessing I need some additional code to actually wire this up but I'm still learning the basics for visual studio packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Below is my workaround:
1. Install and Visual studio 2012 SDK and do as  walkthrough of 2012 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh966591(v=vs.110).aspx
2. upgrade the project to vs2013 version according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512930.aspx

Comment: Can you summarize the link contents in your answer? This is more future-proof.